# Getiing 403 forbidden in Hybris when adding to cart from carousel

Tags: spring-security, carousel, http-status-code-403, sap-commerce-cloud

In Hybris, I am getting a 403 forbidden error in browser console while trying to add a carousel product to the cart, it is happening sometimes and only in the homesite, the rest of the page is working fine. I think it is related with the configuration of the CSRF token but I don't know how to fix it, any clue? Thanks!

Edit: When checking page source code, the hidden CSFR Token attribute is different from the current, maybe because the session is expiring but even after reloading the page and creating a new session, the value is still wrong. How can I ask for the valid token before every call?

Comment: Is the homepage under SSL ?

Comment: @HristoStaykov yes!

Answer (score 1):

You can check your spring-security-config.xml for csrf or configure "csrf.allowed.url.patterns" parameter in your properties file.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but as far as I know that parameter is used to bypass the CSFR checking. What I need to do is to fix the validation and send the proper token.